# updating a record in Laravel 8 throws error, however, record is being updated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

when I update a record in my laravel 8 application, I get the error message below

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'universityname' cannot be null

SQL:

```
update `exam_applications` 
set `universityname` = ?, `graduationyear` = ?, `mbbscert` = ?, `mdcncert` = ?, `certification` = ?, `attestation` = ? 
where `applicationid` = 202108181856139
```

However, checking my database, the record was updated successfully , what could be the problem?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the snippet of the code?

Comment: If you get that SQL error, the record won't be updated. Period.

Comment: you are updating `universityname` column with `null` value which has `not null` constraint in your table

Comment: @Pradeep you are right. I had to add ->(nullable) to the fields from the migration file. THanks